# If $P(E \mid F) < P(E)$ does that mean that $P(F \mid E) < P(F)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I originally thought that this was a false statement, so I've been trying to come up with counter examples. I've spent some time thinking about it like with decks of cards and the probability that an ace is pulled and whatnot, but it always holds true.

Once again the statement is:

If $P(E \mid F) < P(E)$ is true then $P(F \mid E) < P(F)$ is also true.

If this is false like my intuition says is there a good counter example? If not is there a proof. I've tried breaking down the original statement to come up with RHS but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

The proposed claim is indeed true. To conclude so, notice that

\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(E|F) < \textbf{P}(E) & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\textbf{P}(E\cap F)}{\textbf{P}(F)} < \textbf{P}(E)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\textbf{P}(F\cap E)}{\textbf{P}(E)} < \textbf{P}(F)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(F|E) < \textbf{P}(F)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I didn't recognize this ‍♂️.

Comment: @Aidan you are welcome! I am glad I could help.